# get text between an @ sign and a comma

Tags: php, regex

So I am doing a list sort of like twitter where I want members to be able to tweat at each other.

What I want to do is compose a regular expression that will extract all data between the @sign and a comma.

For instance,

```
 @foo, @bar, @foo bar, hello world
```

Currently I have the following expression.

```
 /@([a-z0-9_]+)/i
```

However, that will stop at the space so instead of registering "@foo bar" as on member it will recognize it at just @foo and ignore the bar portion.

Can somebody help me alter that query so that usernames are allowed to have spaces.

Comment: Uhh... did you try adding a space in the range?

Comment: @user, not quite sure about `php`  regexp syntax, but possibly `/@(.+[^,])/i`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
~@([^,]+)~
```

`[^,]` means every char except `,`

#### [DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/FU0QbBGN5U)

Answer (score 1):

If you truly seek to match *all the data* between the @ sign and the comma, you can use

```
/@(.+),/i
```

But what I think you need is...

```
/@([\w +]+),/i
```

...which matches all word characters (letters, numbers and underscores!) and spaces between the @ and the comma signs. View the [demo](http://rubular.com/r/ykPkGG99YH).

Comment: First regex is incorrect unless you need data before first @ and last comma

Comment: +1 for being on both way thinker. i was thinking only the first way.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

`/@([a-z0-9_\s]+)/i`

`\s` is the symbol for space.

Comment: `\s` denotes all whitespace, not just a space.

Answer (score 0):

`/@(.*?),/` `?` makes `*` non-greedy, thats why it's stop after first comma. You should understand that it won't match 
`@foo` without commas

Answer (score -2):

try [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
<?php
$subject = "@foo, @bar, @foo bar, hello world";
$pattern = '/@(.*),.*/';
$matches = preg_match($pattern, $subject, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

**[DEMO of REGEX PATTERN](http://rubular.com/r/dw3MPJ7kJm)**

Comment: Checkout result 4 for this match using your regex http://rubular.com/r/zIlXm1FY9k

Comment: Thanks @Yasky; would u please help me to how to improve above regex, do miss something or i need to change it completely

Comment: @RiaD what does U modifier do?? will u please provide me links to learn and understand regex better.

Comment: It should be not-greedy. It is equialent to /@(.*?),/ http://rubular.com/r/NjURipuQXI